# ContentCachingResponseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray() is empty when testing with MockHttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, servlet-filters

I have a filter for logging some information for each request to a Spring Boot application. Some of this information I need to extract from the body. That's not a problem in itself, but to do so I use `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`, and that is messing up my unit tests.

Here is a simplified version of my filter:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        var wrappedResponse = response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper ? (ContentCachingResponseWrapper) response : new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);
    } finally {        
        System.out.println("Response body: " + new String(wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray()));
        wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
}
```

And here is a simplified version of my test:

```
    void myTest() throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String body = "This is a body that my service might return.";
        var testResp = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        testResp.getWriter().print(body);
        testResp.getWriter().flush();
        testResp.setContentLength(body.length());

        myFilter.doFilterInternal(Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class), testResp, Mockito.mock(FilterChain.class));
    }
```

The problem is that when running my tests, `wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray()` returns an empty array.

Comment: And why should it? The response isn't wrapped, at least your filter doesn't wrap anything. So not sure how you think it shold work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Wouldn't the first line in the finally block wrap the response in a ContentCachingResponseWrapper?

Comment: No it checks if it is an instance of that class and wraps after the fact. The response should be wrapped before the call to `filterchain.doFilter` and passed as the response. The wrapped response should then be used in the `finally` block.

Comment: Thank you. I have probably moved some stuff around while debugging, because this worked before (when not testing). I have changed it now and the behaviour is still the same during testing.

Comment: Which is to be expected as well. As you are writing the response before the `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` has time to intercept it and cache it.

Comment: Ah. That makes a lot of sense! Thank you. Got any idea how I can test this?

Comment: Register behavior/answer on the `filterChain.doFilter` call instead of a no-op mock.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thank you. Feel free to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong with your code

1. Your filter isn't wrapping the response in the `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`
2. You are writing the response before the wrapping has occured on the underlying response, so the `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` has no change of caching the response.

```java
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        var wrappedResponse = response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper ? (ContentCachingResponseWrapper) response : new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);
    } finally {        
        System.out.println("Response body: " + new String(wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray()));
        wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
}
```

Now the response will be wrapped in the wrapper for responses written further down the `FilterChain`. This is also something you can leverage in your testcase by mocking the `FilterChain` and write the response in an answer.

```java
void myTest() throws ServletException, IOException {
  var body = "This is a body that my service might return.";
  var req = new MockHttpServletRequest();
  var res = new MockHttpServletResponse();
  var mockChain = Mockito.mock(FilterChain.class);
  Mockito.when(mockChain.doFilter(any(), any())
    .thenAnswer((it -> {
      var response = it.getArgument(1, HttpServletResponse.class);
      response.getWriter().print(body);
      response.getWriter().flush();
      response.setContentLength(body.length());
      return null;      
     });
   myFilter.doFilterInternal(req, res, mockChain);
}
```

Something along these lines should do the trick.